# Honda CR-V 2001 window winding fault

Tags: honda, power-windows, crv

My crv passenger window goes up only on the door switch and neither up or down on the master switch located on the dashboard.  Any ideas, I have got a new window regulator mechanism, another door switch.  Seems there is power to the door switch. Can't explain it as the regulator worked but sluggish so that why we got a new one.  Doesn't explain these symptoms NOW?

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of these symptoms is failure of the main window switch. It is not common for the door switches to fail. Water intrusion into the motor units is common on this model. It usually presents as slow movement at first, followed by failure. During the period of time that it is moving slowly it is drawing more power which stresses the switches. In this case the fact that is moves rules out problems in the wiring, power supply and ground connections.

Two testing approaches are available.

1) Use a voltmeter and a wiring diagram to test for power and ground at the switches and motor.

2) Replace parts one at a time until the symptoms are gone.